# Найти наиболее часто встречающееся число

Tags: c#

В случайном массиве целых чисел с количеством элементов
N найти наиболее часто встречающееся число. Если таких чисел несколько,
то определить наименьшее из них.

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 4):

Например, с помощью linq:

```
public int FrequentlyNumber(int[] nums)
{
    return nums.GroupBy(x => x)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count())
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
               .ThenBy(x => x.Key)
               .Take(1)
               .Select(x => x.Key)
               .First();
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
Console.WriteLine(FrequentlyNumber(new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4 })); // expected: 2
Console.WriteLine(FrequentlyNumber(new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4 })); // expected: 4
Console.WriteLine(FrequentlyNumber(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })); // expected: 1
```

---

Update. В комментариях @Андрей NOP справедливо указывает, что некоторые шаги излишни и можно сократить:

```
public int FrequentlyNumber(int[] nums)
{
    return nums.GroupBy(x => x)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
               .ThenBy(x => x.Key)
               .Select(x => x.Key)
               .First();
}
```

Comment: ToDictionary — лишняя материализация, можно обойтись без нее. Take+First? Бессмысленно же

Comment: @АндрейNOP Действительно, поправил. Я вот в первом случае не видел этого сокращения (я именно так и мыслил последовательными трансформациями "из этого сейчас можно сделать словарь, из словаря можно вот так поменять данные" не задумавшись над вопросом "а можно ли более коротким путём придти к ответу?"), а во втором видел, но у меня от непонимания как работает технология - так и хочется оставить хинты для различных оптимизаций типа "тут не будет набора, тут будет только одно число" в расчёте что быстрее отработает.